# System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found for XmlRpcProxyGen.Create

Tags: c#

I'm trying to communicate with a python server using XML-RCP but when I try to compile the following code, the exception "System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.'" displays, I've found no documentation about this issue

```
    using CookComputing.XmlRpc;
    using System;


    [XmlRpcUrl("http://192.168.5.211:8000")]
    public interface FlRPC : IXmlRpcProxy
    {
        [XmlRpcMethod("add")]
        int add(int x, int y);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FlRPC proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<FlRPC>();
            Console.WriteLine(proxy.add(2, 3));
        }
    }
```

I just want to skip this issue to continue to work on my project!

Answer (score 2):

If the application you are trying to build is a .NET Core Application the [xmlrpcnet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xmlrpcnet/) package might be exclusively for the .NET Framework.

Try to replace it with Horizon's .NET Core port, [Horizon.XmlRpc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Horizon.XmlRpc.Core/) and see if it helps.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: @5377037: This isn’t a link-only answer. It is usable without the links since the link URIs contain the package names. (Though it’d be better if the link labels were just the package names.)

Comment: @5377037: FYI: I’ve made this change to the post to better clarify this distinction.